# Is there a Groovier way to access properties file?

Tags: gradle, groovy

One can access properties file like that:

```
def props = new Properties()
new File('my.props').withInputStream { props.load(it) }
assert props.foo == 'bar'
```

I think that's quite cumbersome. Isn't there a groovier way?

```
// does not compile
def props = Properties.from(new File('my.props'))
assert props.foo == 'bar'
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe the answer is no.

The doc for [Groovy JDK enhancements](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/index-all.html#_P_) does not contain `java.util.Properties` (compared to, say, `java.io.File`). [This article](http://paweloczadly.github.io/dev/2014/09/23/groovy-reading-and-writing-to-properties-file/) implies prior art for a home-grown solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can always utilize metaprogramming:

```
Properties.metaClass.static.from = { File f ->
    def p = new Properties()
    f.withInputStream { p.load(it) }
    p
}
p = Properties.from(new File('a.properties'))
assert p['a'] == '10'
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any shortcut to create a properties from a file. I'd like to suggest a simple solution without prior variable declaration:

```
p = new File('my.props').withReader { reader -> 
    new Properties().with { 
        load reader
        it
    }
}
```